# Retrieving Params from GET request to fetch the value. (PostMan)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

From postman, I'm trying to send a GET request with params as Key:

- path, Value: `home/guest/images/abc.jpeg`

I want to retrieve the same and use the Value as the argument of my function.
 Somehow I'm unable to get the same, API not being called. Any input shall be helpful.

I'm new to writing REST APIs using Flask Python. I want to get the Value of the Params key: path as the TEST_PATH so that the rest of the code run as it should return the JSONP_data

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from flask import jsonify
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

# set the project root directory as the static folder, you can set others.
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
counter=0

@app.route('/')
def api_root():
    return ('Welcome')


@app.route('/generateTags/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def generateTags1(id):
    file = json.loads(create_task(id))
    TEST_PATH = file['path']
    print(TEST_PATH)
    import DenseNet
    import Inception
    import ResNet
    import SqueezNet
    from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
    prediction = ImagePrediction()
    # TEST_PATH = '/home/anit/Documents/Image Analysis/ImageAI-master/Dataset'

    dense_list=DenseNet.tag(TEST_PATH, DenseNet.prediction)
    dense_list = ['DenseNet'] + dense_list.tolist()[0]
    res_list=ResNet.tag(TEST_PATH, ResNet.prediction)
    res_list = ['ResNet'] + res_list.tolist()[0]
    incept_list=Inception.tag(TEST_PATH, Inception.prediction)
    incept_list = ['Inception'] + incept_list.tolist()[0]
    squeez_list=SqueezNet.tag(TEST_PATH, SqueezNet.prediction)
    squeez_list = ['SqueezNet'] + squeez_list.tolist()[0]
    d = {'filename':dense_list[1], 'models':{}}
    for l in [dense_list,res_list, incept_list, squeez_list]:
        #breakpoint()
        d['models'][l[0]] = l[2:]

    JSONP_data = jsonify(d)
    return JSONP_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run ()
```